# HTTP 404 on Route in Route Setup in HomeController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem with setting up correctly route in my home controller.
I'm trying to set route for my email sing up input field. Here is my cshtml code snippet:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/emailsignup">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
            <span class="input-group-btn btnstateless">
                <input type="submit" id="mailSignup"value="SUBSCRIBE"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'm trying to set route for action in my HomeController.cs
Here is the part of my code:

```
[Route("home/emailsignup")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EmailSignupGet()
        {
                var cVM = new ConfirmedViewModel
                {
                    confirmationTitle = "Thanks!",
                    message = "",
                    nextStep = "<a href=\"/\">Return home</a>"
                };
                return View("Confirmed", cVM);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmailSignup(string email)
        {

            if (UtilsClass.IsValidEmail(email))
            {
Email.GreenArrowHelper.AddOrUpdateUserByEmailFetchAllInfo(email).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var cVM = new ConfirmedViewModel();
                cVM.confirmationTitle = "Thanks!";
                cVM.message = "";
                cVM.nextStep = "<a href=\"/\">Return home</a>";
                return View("Confirmed", cVM);
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorViewModel eVM = new ErrorViewModel
                {
                    title = "Hmm, something's not right.",
                    message = "That doesn't look like a valid email address. Please try again.",
                    nextstep = "<a href=\"/\">Return home</a>"
                };
                return View("Error", eVM);
            }


        }
```

I'm trying to return my messages but instead, I'm getting HTTP 404 on click on subscribe button.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the route on the post action

```
//POST home/emailsignup
[Route("home/emailsignup")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmailSignup(string email) {
    //...
}
```

When using attribute routing on a controller you need to apply it to the desired actions else get the 404 not found as you already encountered.